# SQL Result to XML (Specific Layout)

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have a table in SQL that contains a list of settings for an application per serverID

I want write a SQL statement that produce a specific XML layout.

The basic SQL statement to retrieve this data:

```
SELECT SettingName, SettingValue 
FROM dbo.ServerSettings  
WHERE ServerID = @ServerID
```

I just need to know the correct FOR XML options.

I want to get back a result like the following. Basically using the value of the SettingName field to be the name of the node.

```
<ROOT>
    <COSTRECOVERYSYSTEM_CONNECTION_STRING></COSTRECOVERYSYSTEM_CONNECTION_STRING>
    <COSTRECOVERYSYSTEM_EXTRACT_INTERVAL>60</COSTRECOVERYSYSTEM_EXTRACT_INTERVAL>
    <COSTRECOVERYSYSTEM_FILE_DATESTAMP>yyyyMMdd</COSTRECOVERYSYSTEM_FILE_DATESTAMP>
    <COSTRECOVERYSYSTEM_FILE_EXTENSION>txt</COSTRECOVERYSYSTEM_FILE_EXTENSION>
    <COSTRECOVERYSYSTEM_FILE_NAME>txt</COSTRECOVERYSYSTEM_FILE_NAME>
    <COSTRECOVERYSYSTEM_FILE_PATH>txt</COSTRECOVERYSYSTEM_FILE_PATH>
</ROOT>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in any other query you cannot use a column's value as the output column name. This would need some dynamically created statement and `EXEC()` for its execution.

But you might do something along this:

```sql
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(SettingName VARCHAR(100),SettingValue VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES ('Setting1','1'),('Setting2','2'),('ForbiddenValue','Huh! What about & and <?');

SELECT CAST((
        SELECT '<' + UPPER(t.SettingName) + '>' +
               --this embedded FOR XML will implicitly do the escaping for you
               (SELECT t.SettingValue AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')) +
               '</' + UPPER(t.SettingName) + '>'
        FROM @tbl t
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
       ).value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS XML)
FOR XML PATH('ROOT');
```

In general I would never create XML with string methods. There are so many possible draw backs and traps. But in this case it might be the best choice.

Hint: Be sure, that the setting names are valid XML element names. There are some [XML element naming rules](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can see these links for more information:
1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/for-xml-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017
2. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/learn-sql-server/using-the-for-xml-clause-to-return-query-results-as-xml/

Comment: Yeah those links don't give me the answer.